Get error when using logical backup in PieCloudDB
I encounter the following error when using logical backup in PieCloudDB Database. What steps should I take to resolve this issue?
pg_dump: Dumping the contents of table "xxxx" failed: PQgetResult() failed. pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR: invalid memory alloc request size 18446744073709551613 pg_dump: The command was: COPY xxxxxx (id, active_flag, bkd, blk, go_show, grs, lss, lsv, lt, no_show, value, wl, inv_seg_cabin_id, ind) TO stdout; pg_dump: [parallel archiver] a worker process died unexpectedly


If you have a backup, you can use it to restore; if not, you need to try setting the parameter zero_damaged_pages to true. This method will not modify the physical file, but only change the in-memory cache of corrupted pages to 0.
If configuring the parameter resolves the error, then back up your table and restore it again. If the error continues, you have to identify the precise areas of corruption and delete the corresponding bad blocks, which may lead to some data loss.
